# Javascript Alphanumeric regular expression not taking new line character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following regular expression to check alphanumeric values in an text area.

```
var alphaExp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z\s]+$/;
```

This works fine but when user write comment and hit *enter* key to move to nexe line this validation fails.

How to allow new line character in this expression?

Comment: your code working fine already http://jsfiddle.net/Md5XA/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this regular expression `/^[0-9a-zA-Z\s\r\n]+$/;`

I have added `\r` for carriage return and `\n` for new line.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rJqHb/

Answer (score 1):

`\s` only matches newlines in multi-line mode.

```
var alphaExp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z\s]+$/m;
```

should work.